# Inspection on new work in house with unpermitted work

Tags: inspection

My house's basement was previously partially 'finished' with no permits and poor code compliance. In the interim, I've done some repair work down there. Now I want to do a significant rework and do it properly.

However, we actively use the basement, so I have to do it in sections. Now my question is, when I call an inspector for the rough-in of the new work in part of the basement, are they going to ding me for old unpermitted work?

Comment: Talk to the inspector ahead of time? The "dings" might be useful in calling attention to issues that you might not have seen yet, but then again, they might not, depending on how much you're demo'ing and replacing wholesale

Comment: That's why I call it *'inspector paint'*. In the new drawings there will be areas that are grayed out and say *no work*. If it looks new enough that you did some work there, then maybe. If there's glaringly white PVC over there somewhere, rub some dirt on it ;). Basically it comes down to them believing you that, "it was like that when I got here". - There's a difference between *building* inspectors and those from the bank. Building inspectors are there to do a (specific) job. Bank inspectors are there to (nitpick) make sure *they'll* still have a job once it's all said and done.

Comment: Yes, I cherish old, tarnished EMT conduit for precisely that reason :)

Comment: Many people think code was not followed when looking at old work. I hear this all the time. Even home inspectors are commonly Wrong as they do not know the electrical code from years past and have limited experience. Why is this important?  The date the electrical was installed to code and not modified it is still code compliant today. The wiring is grandfathered and unless changing the use like changing from a residential to a commercial use then a wiring update may be required. But not changing the use a 1960’s home with no gfci’s or arc fault protection is up to code.

Comment: I'm sure, but I'm pretty sure even in the 60's there were rules about not putting a lid on a j-box because it was too full, and about burying splices in the wall.